# Matlab Extend Diagonal by one

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix A, and I'd like to get the matrix `[A 0; 0 1]`. Is there a built function to do this?

So if my matrix is `[2 3; 1 4]`, I'd get back `[2 3 0; 1 4 0; 0 0 1]`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is:

```
newA = A;

newA(end+1,end+1) = 1;
```

This works because you can index outside an array for assignments, because `end` indicates the last element (here in row and column), and because Matlab pads with zeros when you grow an array. If you just want to grow `A`, you can even skip the creation of `newA`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I always use matrix concatenation for problems like this

So for your example:

```
A = [2 3; 1 4]
A = [A A(:,1)*0; A(1,:)*0 1]
```

produces

```
A =

     2     3     0
     1     4     0
     0     0     1
```

The nice thing about this trick is that its very flexible and you can do all sorts of tranformations
very easily. For example

```
A = [2 3; 1 4]
A = [1 A(1,:)*0; A(:,1)*0 A]
```

produces

```
A =

     1     0     0
     0     2     3
     0     1     4
```